# Meet in Google Calendar API

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-meet

How can I add google meet in google calendar api in java?
Please help me. I haven't understood the google documentation.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events. The source code is given here. Here, I want to create event using users gmail account. I have not any G-suite account

```java
Event event = new Event()
    .setSummary(title)
    .setLocation(location)
    .setDescription(description);

DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime( date +"T"+startTime+"+06:00" );//"2020-05-05T11:00:00+06:00");
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
    .setDateTime(startDateTime)
    .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
event.setStart(start);

DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(date +"T"+endTime+"+06:00");//"2020-05-05T12:00:00+06:00");
EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
    .setDateTime(endDateTime)
    .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
event.setEnd(end);

String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"};
event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

EventAttendee attendees[];

attendees = new EventAttendee[allAttendees.size()];

for(int i=0; i<allAttendees.size(); i++){
    // System.out.println(allAttendees.get(i));
    attendees[i] = new EventAttendee().setEmail(allAttendees.get(i));
}
event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
};


Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
    .setUseDefault(false)
    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
event.setReminders(reminders);

String calendarId = "primary";

try {
    abc = service.events().insert(calendarId, event);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String meetingId = event.getHangoutLink();
System.out.println("What is meeting ID? = "+meetingId);
```

Comment: Hi! It would be really helpful if you would provide some code that you have already writen

Comment: source code given

Answer (score 7):

### Answer

***You will need to use the [JAVA API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/) for Google Calendar***

You have to create a new Meet request and then append it to the current event and before that, enable the conferenceDataVersion by setting it to 1. Before using the following code make sure that you have this [setup](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java?authuser=1#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

### Code

```
Event event = new Event()
                        .setSummary(title)
                        .setLocation(location)
                        .setDescription(description);

// Your previous code

/* The code needed - START */

ConferenceSolutionKey conferenceSKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey();
conferenceSKey.setType("eventHangout"); // Non-G suite user
CreateConferenceRequest createConferenceReq = new CreateConferenceRequest();
createConferenceReq.setRequestId("3whatisup3"); // ID generated by you
createConferenceReq.setConferenceSolutionKey(conferenceSKey);
ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData();
conferenceData.setCreateRequest(createConferenceReq);
event.setConferenceData(conferenceData); // attach the meeting to your event

/* The code needed - END */

String calendarId = "primary";

// There’s no need to declare the try-catch block twice

try {
    /* Code changes - START */

    // .setConferenceDataVersion(1) enables the creation of new meetings
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).setConferenceDataVersion(1).execute();

    /* Code changes - END */

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String meetingId = event.getHangoutLink();
System.out.println("What is meeting ID? = "+meetingId);
```

### References

[Google Calendar JAVA API: Event.setConferenceData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/)

[Google Calendar JAVA API: ConferenceData.setCreateRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/ConferenceData.html#setCreateRequest-com.google.api.services.calendar.model.CreateConferenceRequest-)

[Google Calendar JAVA API: CreateConferenceRequest.setRequestId](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/CreateConferenceRequest.html#setRequestId-java.lang.String-)

[Google Calendar JAVA API: ConferenceSolutionKey.setType](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/ConferenceSolutionKey.html#setType-java.lang.String-)

[Google Calendar JAVA API: Calendar.Events.Insert.setConferenceDataVersion](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/Calendar.Events.Insert.html#setConferenceDataVersion-java.lang.Integer-) **The most important**

Comment: I have used the following dependencies.                             
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev305-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

Comment: Can you please describe more in detail what error do you get?

Comment: Yeah, bro. Your code is working. Thanks a lot. May God bless you.<3

Comment: Glad to help! For documentation purposes if you can, please accept the answer that's been helpful to you - it helps other people that have the same issue in the future find the solution too.

Answer (score 3):

The final workable code for me is given below.

```
 Event event = new Event()
            .setSummary(title)
            .setLocation(location)
            .setDescription(description);


    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime( date +"T"+startTime+"+06:00" );//"2020-05-05T11:00:00+06:00");
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
    event.setStart(start);

    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(date +"T"+endTime+"+06:00");//"2020-05-05T12:00:00+06:00");
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
    event.setEnd(end);

    String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"};
    event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

  /*  s1 = "abc@gmail.com";
    s2 = "xyz@gmail.com";

    EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
            new EventAttendee().setEmail(s1),
            new EventAttendee().setEmail(s2),
    };*/



    EventAttendee attendees[];

    attendees = new EventAttendee[allAttendees.size()];

    for(int i=0; i<allAttendees.size(); i++){
       // System.out.println(allAttendees.get(i));
        attendees[i] = new EventAttendee().setEmail(allAttendees.get(i));
    }
    event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));



    EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
            new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
            new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
    };


    Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
            .setUseDefault(false)
            .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
    event.setReminders(reminders);


    ConferenceSolutionKey conferenceSKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey();
    conferenceSKey.setType("hangoutsMeet"); // Non-G suite user
    CreateConferenceRequest createConferenceReq = new CreateConferenceRequest();
    createConferenceReq.setRequestId("3whatisup3"); // ID generated by you
    createConferenceReq.setConferenceSolutionKey(conferenceSKey);
    ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData();
    conferenceData.setCreateRequest(createConferenceReq);
    event.setConferenceData(conferenceData);

    String calendarId = "primary";

    try {
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).setConferenceDataVersion(1).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
    System.out.printf("Hangout Link %s\n", event.getHangoutLink());
```

Comment: It would be helpful it you explained why this was a solution for you, what is that you needed to do. So people like me coming to your code later will have the context.

Comment: The above code is solution for me because I wanted to create Google meet link when the calendar event is created. By using this code, google meet link successfully created with calendar event.

Comment: where to generate the id from?

Answer (score 1):

@Jose Vasquez's answer is right except for one thing.
I changed this line

```
conferenceSKey.setType("eventHangout");
```

to this

```
conferenceSKey.setType("hangoutsMeet");
```

and then everything works fine.